# PHP has no setlogmask?

Tags: php

I am working on a legacy application that runs in PHP.  I'm porting to Centos7, PHP 5.4.16.

I want to write log messages to syslog and wrote a test script:

```
#!/usr/bin/php

<?php

$log_options = LOG_NDELAY | LOG_PID;
$log_priorities = LOG_ERR | LOG_WARNING | LOG_INFO | LOG_DEBUG;  
$log_facility = LOG_LOCAL2;
openlog('test.php', $log_options, $log_facility);

syslog(LOG_ERR, 'LOG_ERR -- this is an error');
syslog(LOG_WARNING, 'LOG_WARNING -- this is a warning');
syslog(LOG_INFO, 'LOG_INFO -- this is info');
syslog(LOG_DEBUG, 'LOG_DEBUG -- this is debug info');
?>
```

What gets written to syslog is this:

```
Aug 14 14:03:28 localhost test.php[32774]: LOG_ERR -- this is an error
Aug 14 14:03:28 localhost test.php[32774]: LOG_WARNING -- this is a warning
Aug 14 14:03:28 localhost test.php[32774]: LOG_INFO -- this is info
```

Note that the debug line wasn't written.  How do you set the log mask?

I'm used to using syslog() in C but not PHP.  I can't figure out anyway to set the log mask (like setlogmask() would in C).

I updated my test script to include error_reporting(E_ALL) and still no LOG_DEBUG:

```
#!/usr/bin/php

<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

$log_options = LOG_NDELAY | LOG_PID;
$log_priorities = LOG_ERR | LOG_WARNING | LOG_INFO | LOG_DEBUG;
$log_facility = LOG_LOCAL2;
openlog('test.php', $log_options, $log_facility);

syslog(LOG_ERR, 'LOG_ERR -- this is an error');
syslog(LOG_WARNING, 'LOG_WARNING -- this is a warning');
syslog(LOG_INFO, 'LOG_INFO -- this is info');
syslog(LOG_DEBUG, 'LOG_DEBUG -- this is debug info');
?>
```

Same thing is written to syslog.

Third edit:

I wrote a small C program and it also doesn't log the debug messages.  Not sure why.  I have three systems and one does log the debug and two don't.  All three are CentOS7.

Here's the program:

```
#include <syslog.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  setlogmask(LOG_UPTO(LOG_DEBUG));
  openlog("test", LOG_NDELAY | LOG_PID, LOG_LOCAL2);

  syslog(LOG_ERR, "LOG_ERR -- this is an error");
  syslog(LOG_WARNING, "LOG_WARNING -- this is a warning");
  syslog(LOG_INFO, "LOG_INFO -- this is info");
  syslog(LOG_DEBUG, "LOG_DEBUG -- this is debug info");

  closelog();

}
```

So it looks like this is a combination of two things.  What alariva and Progman said.  I selected what alariva said because it's closest to the original PHP problem.

Fourth Edit:

The lack of LOG_DEBUG messages was a simple rule in /etc/rsyslog.conf:

```
#*.none;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                /var/log/messages
*.debug;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                /var/log/messages
```

The first line (commented out) was the original.  The second line allowed the debug messages to come through.

Comment: what if you call `closelog` at the end of the script?

Comment: Calling closelog() didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because PHP logs errors on a pre-defined *error level* basis, you may change this with `error_reporting()` and setting ALL levels to be accepted:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); // before any log call
```

equivalent

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
```

This will include debug level.

You may also change this at config (php.ini) level.

[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Comment: Thanks, I updated my test script and question.  E_ALL doesn't seem to include LOG_DEBUG.  Which is odd since the PHP manual includes LOG_DEBUG.

Comment: Just as a troubleshooting, does `grep -r /var/log/* FINDTHISLINE` find anything if you `syslog(LOG_DEBUG, 'FINDTHISLINE');` ?

Comment: I tried it with grep -r FINDTHISLINE /var/log/* and no, it didn't find anything.

Comment: It looks like your log messages are getting filtered by a sys-wide config, I agree with Progman in that way. Buy I honestly don't know what Centos config might be like in these terms. This is one of the closest references I've found about that https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=28047 and https://codybonney.com/logging-and-viewing-php-errors-on-centos-6-3/

Comment: I agree.  I wrote a C program and it does the same thing.  See my edited question.

Comment: In that case it looks like php has little to do here. You may want to edit your question to make focus on centos and syslog so you bring experts atenttention from that area

Comment: I agree we got a little off track, but I think your answer about error_reporting(E_ALL) answers the original question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible that the logging is also affected by the configuration of your system logger. If you use the `LOG_PERROR` flag you will see that all the `syslog()` calls gets logged to the standard error.

You have to check the configuration of your system logger to see if there are settings which defines a minimum required log level (so the log files don't get spammed with debug messages all the time).

Comment: Yes.  The LOG_PERROR does work on the C program and it shows the debug statement which isn't in /var/log/messages.